# Report Builder 3.0 CTP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ctp

I have downloaded MS SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 CTP recently. I am bit confused and have following questions:

1. Can I use Report Builder 3.0 with MS SQL server 2008 Express with Reporting services (NOT MS SQL Server 2008 R2 CTP)?
2. Is there any time limit is attached with usage of Report Builder 3.0 CTP, as it is CTP version? Generally CTP versions are for evaluation and have time limit like 180 days or something like that.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works only with 2008 R2 no matter what the edition. I'm guessing that 3.0 is included as part of the SQL Server license just like 2.0.